# Does Windows Server 2008 R2 standard edition support cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, cluster

I want to install sql server 2008 r2 edition in a cluster environment. Can I use Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It [looks like](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx) [you need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008#Failover_Clustering) to go to Server 2008 Enterprise or Data Centre for clustering, or Itanium for that usage case. My assumption would be once you have the OS sorted, you need to ensure that you're running a version of SQL that supports clustering

So, to answer your question - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard cannot be used for a SQL cluster

Answer (score 5):

Enterprise and Data Centre versions only sorry.

Comment: Factually incorrect. Correct answer even has link to MS documentation sating the answer.

Comment: In ye olden days (SQL Server 2000), this would have been true. It changed 5 years ago with Workgroup edition  SQL Server 2005 becoming the old "standard". See http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx. I see you do more Oracle from your answers... inbuilt bias? :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but you're both incorrect and I am in fact correct - the combination being asked about (SQL 2008 on Server 2008 Standard) will NOT support clustering (even 2-node) as Server 2008 Standard does not support Failover Clustering at all. The document that gbn links to regards what level of clustering SQL 2008 supports, it still requires a supporting OS under it and this combination won't work. Have a look at the bottom of this link; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Windows 2008R2 Standard Edition does not support Failover cluster.  The failover cluster doesn't even show up in the list of features. I just checked it. Only Ent and Datacenter supports it.